# Prove $rk(A - AXW^{-1}Y^TA) = rk(A) - rk(AXW^{-1}Y^TA)$ : A general form of Wedderburn’s rank-one reduction formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, matrix-rank

I have difficulty proving the following rank equality , which becomes the  Wedderburn’s rank-one reduction formula when $k=1$ .

Let $A\in M_{m,n}(F)$ . If $X\in M_{n,k}$ and $Y\in M_{m,k}(F)$ , and if $W=Y^TAX$ is non-singular , then we have rank equality
$rk(A - AXW^{-1}Y^TA) = rk(A) - rk(AXW^{-1}Y^TA)$ .

I could only obtain some information :

by full rank factorization , $rk(W)=k \iff W=Y^T(AX) \iff  W=(Y^TA)X $ such that
$rk(Y^T)=rk(AX)=rk(Y^TA) = rk(X) =k$ . [ For the first "iff" : This is because $C(W)\subseteq C(Y^T) \implies k \le rk(Y^T) $ but  $ rk(Y^T) \le k$ . Similarly , $R(W)\subseteq R(AX)\implies k \le rk(AX)$ but $ rk(AX) \le k$ . ]

$W^{-1}$ is non-singular . Since multiplication with non-singular matrices will not change rank , apply full rank factorization again to get $rk(AX(W^{-1}Y^TA)) = k$ .

Obviously in general $rk(U-V) \neq rk(U)-rk(V)$  for any compatible matrices $U,V$ . But I don't see why the equality holds in this case .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\operatorname{rank}(A)=r$ and $A=UV^T$ be a [rank factorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization), where $U\in M_{m,r}(F)$ and $V\in M_{n,r}(F)$ have full column ranks. Let $B=Y^TU$ and $C=V^TX$. Then $W=BC$. Since $U$ and $V$ have full column ranks, the ranks of
$$
\begin{aligned}
AXW^{-1}Y^TA&=UC(BC)^{-1}BV^T\\
\text{and}\quad A-AXW^{-1}Y^TA&=U\left(I_r-C(BC)^{-1}B\right)V^T\\
\end{aligned}
$$
are those of $C(BC)^{-1}B$ and $I_r-C(BC)^{-1}B$ respectively. However, as $C(BC)^{-1}B$ and $I_r-C(BC)^{-1}B$ are mutually complementary projections, their ranks must add up to $r=\operatorname{rank}(A)$. Hence the result follows.